# Refreshing gridview to get latest values after update while using datasourceid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that runs a rowcommand to update values in the DB. everything works, except that after running the update the gridview does not refresh with the newest values of the table. I've seen many solutions to solve this problem, most of them stating simply, "just rebind the gridview"

I've tried just running the binding of the gridview, but this does nothing to refresh the gridview.

I've also tried reassigning the datasource to the objectdatasource used when first creating the table like so:

```
GridViewHolder.DataSource = MachineDataSet;
GridViewHolder.DataBind();
```

However, I ended up getting an error saying: that both datasource and the datasourceid is declared and to remove one definition.

I would appreciate it greatly if someone could tell me what i am doing wrong with my gridview?

Below you will find my gridview and codebehind for the rowcommand.

Gridview: note: I removed all the unnecessary context to make it easier to read, if you require more information i will throw up the entire code for the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHolder" 
                      runat="server" 
                      AllowPaging="True" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                                                             
                      EnableViewState="False"
                      DataKeyNames="ID"                          
                      OnRowCommand="GridViewHolder_RowCommand" 
                      DataSourceID="MachineDataSet">
            <RowStyle BackColor="Transparent" 
                      HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <Columns>                    
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Assign New Values" 
                                 CommandName="AssignNewValue" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"
                                 ItemStyle-Width="25px">
                    <ItemStyle Width="25px" Wrap="True" />
                </asp:ButtonField>
            </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

codebehind:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Handles the rowcommand event button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source control event</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs"/> instance containing the even data.</param>
    protected void GridViewHolder_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Debug("Entering Row Command");
        if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("AssignNewValue") == 0)
        {
            try
            {

                logger.Debug("Entering AssignNewValue Command");
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridView gv = (GridView)Panel1.FindControl("GridViewHolder");
                GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[index];
                Label machineID = (Label)row.FindControl("MachineIDLabel");
                int machineid = Convert.ToInt32(machineID.Text);
                string machinetypeid = MachineTypeComboBox.SelectedValue;
                string machinemodelid = MachineModelComboBox.SelectedValue;
                try
                {
                    if (machinetypeid != "" || machinemodelid != "")
                    {
                        if (machinetypeid != "")
                        {
                            inputsService.UpdateMachineTypes(machineid, machinetypeid);
                        }
                        if (machinemodelid != "")
                        {
                            inputsService.UpdateMachineModels(machineid, machinemodelid);
                        }

                        UpdateSucceed.Visible = true;
                        logger.Debug("AssignNewValue - Database successfully updated!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UpdateFail.Visible = true;
                        logger.Debug("AssignNewValue - Database had no data selected to be updated.");
                    }                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.ErrorFormat("AssignNewValue - Failed to update the table, ex = {0}", ex);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.ErrorFormat("AssignNewValue Failed to complete, {0}", ex);
            }

            logger.Debug("Leaving AssignNewValue Command");
        }
        logger.Debug("Leaving Row Command");
    }
```

Datasource code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MachineDataSet"
                               runat="server" 
                               SelectMethod="GetMachineSiteDetails"                                                          
                               TypeName="Datamart.UI.Reporting.Web.FilteredReportInputsSvc.FilteredReportInputsService" 
                               EnableCaching="True">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="siteid" Type="String" />
             </SelectParameters>
         </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "However, i end up getting an error saying: that both datasource and the datasourceid is declared and to remove one definition." From what I can recall you must use one or the other. In your code-behind you maybe able to get away with just doing a .Databind() call

Comment: @jonc i tried doing a .databind() call as well which does not throw an error, but it doesn't refresh the gridview after the updates.

Comment: Can you post your DataSource definition code? For MachineDataSet

Comment: @jonc okay i added it for you

Answer (score 2):

I see you have this in your code:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)Panel1.FindControl("GridViewHolder")
GridViewHolder.DataSource = MachineDataSet;
GridViewHolder.DataBind();
UpdateSucceed.Visible = true;
```

When it should be:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)Panel1.FindControl("GridViewHolder")
gv.DataSource = MachineDataSet;
gv.DataBind();
UpdateSucceed.Visible = true;
```

However, I would have this in a function and call it in the `page_load` event, also on the `row_command`. But you should not have  it on the definition of the gridview:

```
 DataSourceID="MachineDataSet">
```

The DataSourceID should be used only when you have a DataSource control in the page.

Edit: Remember, if you Bind your gridview from the code behind, you will have to do a couple of tweaks in the code to be able to do Paging/Sorting in the Gridview. If you need help with that you just need to do a simple search and you will find it for sure.
Good luck!

Comment: So i should only use the datasourceid if i have something like this one the page:

Comment: You should only use DataSourceID to specify the ID of the Control "that represents the data source from which the data-bound control retrieves its data." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.datasourceid.aspx

Comment: So yeah @James213, your datasource control (ObjectDataSource MachineDataSet) looks fine, but you should either use DataSourceID or DataSource not both.

Comment: so i tried to run the gridview using datasource instead of datasourceid and using a databind method as well as running that in the pageload as i'll show in my question, but now i'm getting this error: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`